# Dynamic message types

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS but have experience with DDS real-time pub/sub middleware.  DDS has the concept of dymanic message type registration, which allows you to define a message type at run-time rather than compile time.  See section 7.5.2 in: portals.omg.org/dds/sites/default/files/x-types_ptc_11-03-11.pdf.  This allows DDS clients change the message structure without recompiling the application ( i.e. by reading message structure from IDL). Is there a similar concept in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65876/dynamic-message-types/) by [mmcbroom](https://answers.ros.org/users/5226/mmcbroom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK: No.

Changing the structure in general would be impossible for c++ nodes. Technically that could be done for python nodes, but in that case all involved nodes would need to get that information from somewhere. I don't think there are any functionalities for doing that at runtime.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-25**:
As @dornhege mentioned it is possible in python to run the generators. We have done a few prototypes of things which do this. With the modularity of nodes only the ones which want the specific message need to be restarted. So you don't need to restart the entire system, but only affected parts.